# Using spel expression in jpql takes 20 second in specific case

Tags: java, jpql, spring-el

This is the jpql code (it's part of a spring rest data endpoint so there is not much overhead).

This is the minimal example I could get the bug with. The original code was much more complicated and the :#{false} originally contained a method call.

```
@RestResource(path = "forUser")
@Query("select distinct o from Organ o join o.meetings om where " +
    "om.id in (select m.id from Meeting m join m.organ mo join mo.organCredentials oc join oc.organCredentialPersons ocp join ocp.person p where p.username = :#{@securityService.getCurrentUserUsername()}) " +
    "or :#{false} = true")
Set<Organ> findForCurrentUser();
```

=> takes 13 seconds

This endpoint is really slow. It takes 13 seconds to get an answer.

Now take the exact same code, but replace :#{false} by "false" or :#{true}. and it now takes less than 1 second.

```
@RestResource(path = "forUser")
@Query("select distinct o from Organ o join o.meetings om where " +
    "om.id in (select m.id from Meeting m join m.organ mo join mo.organCredentials oc join oc.organCredentialPersons ocp join ocp.person p where p.username = :#{@securityService.getCurrentUserUsername()}) " +
    "or false = true")
Set<Organ> findForCurrentUser();
```

=> takes ~1s

```
@RestResource(path = "forUser")
@Query("select distinct o from Organ o join o.meetings om where " +
    "om.id in (select m.id from Meeting m join m.organ mo join mo.organCredentials oc join oc.organCredentialPersons ocp join ocp.person p where p.username = :#{@securityService.getCurrentUserUsername()}) " +
    "or :#{true} = true")
Set<Organ> findForCurrentUser();
```

=> takes ~1s

Honestly I'm stumped. our team gave up on making this work and took an alternative approach due to lack of time, but I would really like to know what is going on here.